# Question about inverse limit

Tags: commutative-algebra, definition

I'm puzzled by the definition of inverse limit in this [Wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseLimit.html).

I thought if an object was defined by a universal property it meant that the object is unique up to unique isomorphism. This would mean that in the article I linked, $\alpha$ should be a unique isomorphism not just a homomorphism as written in the article. Is this a typo?

And I have another question: if someone asks me what an inverse limit is, would I be giving a correct answer if I answered as follows:

The inverse limit of an inverse system $(X_i, f_{ij})$ is the unique pair $(X, \pi_i)$ (where $X$ is an object and $\pi_i$ are morphisms such that $f_{ij} \circ \pi_i = \pi_j$) such that for any pair $(Y, \pi_i^\prime)$ (with $f_{ij} \circ \pi_i^\prime = \pi_j^\prime$) there exists a unique isomorphism $u^{-1}: X \to Y$ such that the following diagram commutes:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, $\alpha$ is supposed to be just a morphism. Their definition is correct.

Comment: See also the categorial definition of [limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_%28category_theory%29) in general.

Comment: @MattN I suppose you follow meta, but I'll write a comment anyway. I've noticed that during the last month you asked (on some days) 3 questions or more, so I wanted to make sure that you know about 50 questions/month (=30 days) quota, which has recently been implemented at MSE, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770).

Comment: Dear @MartinSleziak, thank you very much for this. No, I don't follow meta. I am very grateful for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing two things here:

1) In general there is only a unique *homomorphism* not an isomorphism.

2) The inverse limit is still unique up to unique isomorphism.

The reason that you still have 2) is that if you had inverse limits $X$ and $Y$ then you had the universal property for *both* of them. So you have unique homomorphisms $X\to Y$ and $Y\to X$. You can show that their compositions are the identities (by invoking the universal property for a third time.)

**Edit** To clarify regarding the comments: You have the universal propery for an object $X$. Then you can test it for any objects $Y$ which comes with the according $\pi_i$. You get a homomorphism $f:Y\to X$. Note that $Y$ can be a fairly arbitrary object. Only if $Y$ *also* has the universal property you get a map in the other direction which then turns out to be an inverse.

**Edit2**: Your example is pretty good so I'll work with it. So let $X_n=[-\frac1n,\frac1n]$ with the obvious inclusions as maps between them. 
Which candidates for the inverse limit do we have? First note that $X$ comes with maps (i.e. inclusions) to all of the $X_n$, so $X$ is a subset of every $X_n$ and therefore a subset of the intersection. In our example $X$ can only be $\{0\}$ or $\emptyset$, since those are the only subsets of the intersection. Note that the class of all candidates at this point is the class of all "$Y$" at which we have to test in the next step.

Now we turn to the universal property: for any test-set $Y$ which is a subset of the intersection we want to have a morphism (inclusion) $Y\subset X$. Thus $X$ must be *contained in* the intersection (step 1) and also *contain* all other sets with this property (step 2), which leaves us with $X=\{0\}$.

This is somewhat the whole idea of what is going on there. In general $X$ has to be "small enough" to come with maps into all the $X_n$, and then it must be the "biggest" among all objects with this property.

Comment: But isn't the last part in your answer exactly the same as saying they are two sided inverses which means it's an isomorphism?

Comment: I mean I could replace "homo" by "iso" in the universal property, no?

Comment: I answered you comments in the edit. I hope this clarifies things. If you are unsure you can always try an easy example. Maybe the category of sets with inclusions as morphisms. Then the inverse limit $X$ will be the intersection of the $X_i$, but you still get unique morphisms for any $Y\subset X$ to $X$.

Comment: Dear @Simon, thank you very much for this example. I tried to think about $X_n = [-\frac1n , \frac1n]$ with $i_n : X_n \hookrightarrow X_{n-1}$. How do I compute the inverse limit of this? I don't really see how it should be the intersection of $X_n$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand both, what I mixed up and also how to see that it's the intersection.

Comment: Dear @Simon, it also works the other way: $X_n = [-n,n]$, with $t_n$ the map scaling the numbers appropriately. I actually prefer that because then the $t_n$ go into the "right" direction : )

Comment: (continued) I have one more question about this: in universal properties, the homo. sometimes goes out of the universal object or into it, depending on whether it's initial or terminal. Knowing not much category theory I find it hard to remember which direction the homo. goes. Is there an easy way to spot initial (terminal) objects so that I can remember which way it goes?